# When a phenomenon, usually a proper name, becomes an adjective

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

At some point I came across a term for an adjective that has been formed out of a proper noun. It happens often in the music, art and literary world, i.e. "Sufjanian" or "Dylan-esque." Other common usages are "Seusical" (referring to Dr. Seuss), "Steinbeckian" and "Kerouacian." What is that type of word called? I am almost positive it has a name. It's incredible to me as these terms are created when someone contributes something so unique and original to the world that they've ushered in a new paradigm against which their successors and peers are evaluated. I can't for the life of me remember what this is called.

Comment: *-ian,* (TFD: relating to, belonging to, or resembling) *-esque* (Wikctionary: in the style or manner of) etc., are suffixes to form adjectives. See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-ian & http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-esque

Comment: Orwellian, Kunian, Freudian...  good question.

Comment: A special case of eponyms? Is there a more specific word than eponym? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym

Comment: I guess it could be called _eponymous adjective_.

Comment: Thank you all for weighing in! I think "eponymous adjective" is accurate, but it's not the term I'm after.

Comment: [nonetheless. . .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English)

Answer (score 2):

That is an eponymous adjective

Comment: +1, Named after something else or deriving from an existing name or word: "Programs such as He-Man and Masters of the Universe ... were all created with the explicit purpose of selling the eponymous toys to children